# Particle System is not Playing

Tags: unity

I made a simple spaceship that has a particlesystem. When I press "space" button, spaceship should fly and particle system should instantiate and play. But it's not playing. It seems in hierarchy as clone but not playing.

[As you see, particle effect is instantiating but not playing. It should play at bottom of spaceship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEZAy.png)

Those are codes

```
void FlyShip()
{


    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {

        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);


        if (!takeoffSound.isPlaying)
        {

            // _rocketJetParticle is gameobject. 
            _rocketJetParticle = Instantiate(rocketJetParticle, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 4, transform.position.z), transform.rotation);
            takeoffSound.Play();

        }

    }

    else 
    {
        //Destroy(_rocketJetParticle);
        takeoffSound.Stop();
        
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you mean to tick the "Play on Awake" checkbox, if not manually starting the particle system via script?

Comment: I wanted to play particle system when I instantiate gameobject. But It wasn't playing. I found the solution. If you don't tick "Play on Awake" ,  the particle system attached to gameobject doesn't work. I didn't know that. @DMGregory

Comment: Want to share your solution as an Answer below?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

If you instantiate a particle effect and want it to play when it instantiate you should tick "Play on Awake" box